# Xcode won't build for Generic device

Tags: ios, xcode

`Xcode` does not build or archive when `GenericiOSDevice` is selected gives error,

```
error: Invalid bitcode signature
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

but when a real device is selected it builds or archives successfully app runs without any issue.

`Xcode` version is `10.1`. I am stuck on this for quite a while now. Previously it was giving me an error that library not found for -`lJGProgressHud` than i got it resolved by reinstalling Pods. But now i am stuck on this and don't know how to fix this.Currently i have set `BitCodeEnable = No`.

Comment: i was able to resolve this by changing deployment target from 10.3 to 11.0 , still don't know how it was causing the error.